# Escape reserved keyword in Python [Protocol Buffer autogenerated class]

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

so I'm sort of in a fix.
I'm using Google protocol buffers, and it just so happens that one of the fields in the schema is named "from". 
I'm using python, so everytime I try to access it, I get a syntax error.
[ex - SomeClass.from  -> Syntax error ]

Is there anyway to somehow access the field without using its identifier?

Maybe a way to escape reserved keywords in Python ? (One of the answers already says no, but...)

Or maybe some protobuf specific solution?

Thanks

Comment: The general answer is `getattr(variable, "from")` but there may be a protocol-buffer-specific answer that's less typing and that I don't know of.

Comment: Thanks ! I really should have searched more thoroughly I guess. I sort of got hung up on escaping the keyword :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you pull your data, you can always save the `from` into `from_` (the pythonic way of avoiding namespace clashes) by using the `getattr(var, "from")` statement; Ie

```
SomeClass # is a protocol-buffer
SomeClass.from_ = getattr(SomeClass, "from")
```

And then you an just use `.from_` as you would otherwise.